# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. XVII

Tags: cipher, story

Sorry for the long break everyone! It's been hectic. Here goes XVII:

---

There is another chamber of the labyrinth which contains yet another inscription on the wall:

[image: inscription]

[image: inscription]

Once again, there is a keyboard and you have to type the correct response in. You have a feeling that this is going to be the end of the labyrinth, once and for all. Who knows what adventures await you later!

---

## HINTS: (0% points deduction)

1. > https://www.pvvvpkiyplw.info/vwuiuvvmitaij.php (use original image for help with this hint)

---

**Current Points:**
Joshua Bizley -- <strike>24</strike> <strike>19</strike> 14 points

Shoover -- <strike>15</strike> <strike>40</strike> 109 points

Omega Krypton -- <strike>40</strike> <strike>60</strike> 67 points

Jan Ivan -- 100 points

El-Guest -- 65 points

Stiv -- 83 points

SEE PART XI FOR INFORMATION ON HOW POINTS WORK

Comment: Are you sure the first two symbols aren't the wrong way around?

Comment: (Also, there's a pair of adjacent symbols that should maybe be replaced with another one. I am being vague to reduce spoiling risk :-).)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - Everything seems to be correct, I believe...

Comment: Is it meant to be obvious what "original image" means in the hint?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan -- It just means the original inscription on the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password you must type is:

> **FELINE**

Why? Start by noticing that the inscription is written using:

> The [Elder Futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark) runic alphabet.

Translating, we get:

> CSISJTNEVTNEERHTNNET

What does this mean?

> Well, nothing as it is. But let's reverse it to get:
>  TENNTHREENTVENTJSISC
>
>  Splitting this string into smaller parts, we can form something resembling words:
>  TEN N THREE N TVENTJ-SISC
>
>  And when you consider that the Elder Futhark does not have direct equivalents for some modern-day letters, this appears to be an attempt to spell out (replacing unavailable letters with pseudo-phonetics):
>  **TEN AND THREE AND TWENTY-SIX**

At first glance this seems to suggest that we should type:

> **10 3 26**

into the keyboard. However, this means very little by itself (and converting into A1Z26 yields the pretty unfruitful-looking 'JCZ'); plus it makes no use of the cheese image as things stand. So how can we find a word which better ties together these numbers and the picture? Start by noting the following:

> 1. The image is of *Cheshire cheese*, specifically (taken from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheshire_cheese)).
>
>  2. If we look up symbols in the Periodic Table for elements whose atomic numbers match those that we have found (a fairly common way to convert numbers to letters in puzzles), we get **Ne-Li-Fe** (Neon, Lithium and Iron).

What links these two?

> Well, perhaps the most common association with 'Cheshire' (aside from the English county) is ***the Cheshire Cat*** - a character from *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* by Lewis Carroll. This is a nudge for us to notice that if we reverse the order of the chemical symbols (in exactly the same way as we did when reading the runes) we obtain the word **Fe-Li-Ne** - a word relating to *cats*...   This word - the link between the numbers and the hint image - is thus our password!

Comment: +1 because you are definitely heading down a most correct path... Try to use the second image that's there as well. It provides you a little hint of what to do next!!! Congratulations, you have 45 points (you are very close now).

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath How about now? Or is it something else linked with the character I have identified? (E.g. rot13(FZVYR)?)

Comment: Oh, very nice. Now that the runes have been revealed I can explain my cryptic comments earlier. (1) Shouldn't it be rot13(FVPF engure guna FVFP)? (2) rot13(Gur GU fbhaq unf vgf bja ehar, naq G+U jbhyq or n G fbhaq sbyybjrq ol na U fbhaq.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I had the same reservation about the C and S... I would love to know if there is a dialect or language where the order is considered inconsequential :)

Comment: Very well done! *Feline* is the correct answer. Total 83 points...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Thanks - I've tidied up the flow of the answer to capture this :)